# Issue while adding location service in build.gradle in android

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, build.gradle, androidx

I want to add this google play location services in android

**`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'`**

and my support:appcompat library is

**`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`**

**`targetSdkVersion is 27`**

**`compileSdkVersion is 27`**

when try to build getting error

> Android resource linking failed
>   D:\AndroidStudioProject\GpsLocationApp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2015: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>
> D:\AndroidStudioProject\GpsLocationApp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2015: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
>   error: failed linking references.

Comment: Delete build folder, than clean and rebuild project.

Comment: Not working same error

Comment: try with a downgraded version of location service

Comment: When i downgrade the location service getting this error **ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
 is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:12:5-36:19 to override.**

Answer (score 2):

Google Play services and Firebase migrated to AndroidX in the latest release. 
It means that you are using both, support libraries and androidx libraries.

You can:

- migrate to androidx as described below
- downgrade your google play services dependencies (but it is not a real solution because you have to migrate before or after)

You can check the [official release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019):

> **Warning:** This release is a **MAJOR** version update and breaking change.
>   The latest update to Google Play services and Firebase includes the following changes:

Migration from Android Support Libraries to Jetpack (AndroidX) Libraries. Libraries will not work unless you make the following changes in your app:

- Upgrade `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to v3.2.1 or later.
- **Upgrade `compileSdkVersion` to 28 or later.**
- Update your app **to use Jetpack (AndroidX)**; follow the instructions in [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Also about the specific error described in the answer:

The error is:

> AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>   AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found

Change the `compileSdkVersion` to:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
```

[`fontVariationSettings`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#fontVariationSettings) and [`ttcIndex`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#ttcIndex) were added in api **level 28**.

Comment: Thank you for a simple, clear answer. I had similar issues when adding location services to a brand new app, and these steps solved it.